# Debian Testing: Не отображаются список открытых программ в Latte Dock 0.8.4

Tags: linux, debian, kde

Установлен Debian Testing с KDE Plasma 5.14. [Собрал](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/latte-dock) из исходников и установил Latte Dock.

**Проблема:** Док запустился, но на нет значков запущенных окон. Только виджет аналоговых часов. Добавлял виджет "Панель задач (только значки)". Но это не то. Раньше при первом запуске нормально отображались значки запущенных программ.

**Вопрос:** Как включить отображение иконок запущенных программ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы включить отображение запущенных приложений, надо на док/панель добавить виджет Latte.